# phinx migration 'up' vs. 'change' function

Tags: php, sql, version-control, migration, phinx

I have used phinx migration and used it's 'up' and 'change' functions but i did'nt notice any difference between them. Below is my migration file.

```
    <?php

use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;

class MediaManager extends AbstractMigration
{

    public function up()
    {
        if($this->hasTable('uss_dish')){
            $dish = $this->table('uss_dish');
            $dish   -> addColumn('coordinates','text',array('after' => 'district_id','default' => NULL))
                    -> save();
        }
    }

    public function change()
    {
        if($this->hasTable('uss_dish')){
            $dish = $this->table('uss_dish');
            $dish   -> addColumn('coordinates','text',array('after' => 'district_id','default' => NULL))
                    -> save();
        }
    }

}
```

Can anybody tell me the difference between these two functions ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phinx 0.2.0 added a new feature called reversible migrations. You can implement reversible migrations using `change` method. If you have implemented `change` method, you don't really need to write `down` or `up` methods. While migrating up your logic in `change` method will be executed and Phinx will figure out how to migrate down automatically for you.

Reversible migrations are helpful when you are defining table structure etc.

**Example (Reversible Migrations using Change Method)**

```
<?php

use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;

class CreateUserLoginsTable extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * Write your reversible migrations using this method.
     *
     * More information on writing migrations is available here:
     * http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#the-abstractmigration-class
     *
     * The following commands can be used in this method and Phinx will
     * automatically reverse them when rolling back:
     *
     *    createTable
     *    renameTable
     *    addColumn
     *    renameColumn
     *    addIndex
     *    addForeignKey
     *
     * Remember to call "create()" or "update()" and NOT "save()" when working
     * with the Table class.
     */
    public function change()
    {
        // create the table
        $table = $this->table('user_logins');
        $table->addColumn('user_id', 'integer')
              ->addColumn('created', 'datetime')
              ->create();
    }

    /**
     * Migrate Up.
     */
    public function up()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Migrate Down.
     */
    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

**Example (Same migration as above without using change method)**

```
<?php

use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;

class CreateUserLoginsTable extends AbstractMigration
{


    /**
     * Migrate Up.
     */
    public function up()
    {
       // create the table
        $table = $this->table('user_logins');
        $table->addColumn('user_id', 'integer')
              ->addColumn('created', 'datetime')
              ->create();
    }

    /**
     * Migrate Down.
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('user_logins');
    }
}
```

Read more about [Reversible Migrastions Phinx](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html).

Comment: fwiw, the documentation says that the "up" and "down" functions are ignored if the "change" exists. http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#the-change-method